# How to setup eclipse for using jitsi from github on linux?

Tags: java, eclipse, github, ant, jitsi

I want to use the [libjitsi project](https://github.com/jitsi/libjitsi) from github on my debian. On their homepage I found a good introduction for cloning the project, setup eclipse and using ant to build the project.
If I use make-and-deploy with ant (on the build.xml) I got this output:

```
Buildfile: /media/Volume/linux/eclipse/git_repos/jitsi/build.xml
clean-bundle-repositories:
init:
-pre-version:
version:
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to /media/Volume/linux/eclipse/git_repos/jitsi/classes
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
    [javac] 1 warning
     [echo] Jitsi version 2.5.0.build.by.SVN
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /media/Volume/linux/eclipse/git_repos/jitsi/classes
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
    [javac] 1 warning
resource:
native2ascii:
bundle-sc-launcher:
load-properties:
bundle-util:
      [jar] Building jar: /media/Volume/linux/eclipse/git_repos/jitsi/sc-bundles/util.jar
bundle-service-dns:
bundle-impl-dns:
bundle-dns-config:
bundle-splash-screen:
bundle-configuration:
bundle-configuration-slick:
bundle-history:
bundle-history-slick:
bundle-messagehistory:
bundle-msghistory-slick:
bundle-callhistory:
bundle-callhistory-slick:
bundle-popupmessagehandler-slick:
bundle-netaddr:
bundle-netaddr-slick:
bundle-slickless:
bundle-slick-runner:
bundle-sip:
      [jar] Building jar: /media/Volume/linux/eclipse/git_repos/jitsi/sc-bundles/protocol-sip.jar
      [jar] gov/nist/core/CommonLogger.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/CommonLoggerLog4j.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/Debug.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/DuplicateNameValueList.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/GenericObject.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/GenericObjectList.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/Host.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/HostNameParser.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/HostPort.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/InternalErrorHandler.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/LexerCore.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/LogLevels.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/LogWriter.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/Match.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/MultiMap.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/MultiValueMap.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/MultiValueMapImpl.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/NameValue.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/NameValueList.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/PackageNames.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/ParserCore.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/Separators.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/ServerLogger.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/StackLogger.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/StringTokenizer.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/ThreadAuditor$ThreadHandle.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/ThreadAuditor.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/Token.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/net/AddressResolver.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/net/DefaultNetworkLayer.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/net/NetworkLayer.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/core/net/SslNetworkLayer.class already added, skipping
      [jar] gov/nist/javax/sdp/parser/Lexer.class already added, skipping
bundle-sip-slick:
bundle-fileaccess:
bundle-fileaccess-slick:
bundle-neomedia:
bundle-ldap:
bundle-googlecontacts-service:
bundle-googlecontacts:
bundle-hid-service:
bundle-hid:
bundle-resource-manager:
bundle-resources-skinpack:
bundle-resources-defaultpack:
bundle-protocol:
bundle-protocol-media:
bundle-icq:
bundle-icq-slick:
bundle-mock:
bundle-smacklib:
bundle-jmdnslib:
bundle-jabber:
bundle-jabber-slick:
bundle-commons-lang:
bundle-swing-ui:
bundle-ui-service:
bundle-jnalib:
bundle-phonenumbers:
bundle-slf4j:
bundle-irc-api:
bundle-irc:
bundle-plugin-ircaccregwizz:
bundle-msn:
bundle-msn-slick:
bundle-yahoo:
bundle-yahoo-slick:
bundle-contactlist:
meta-contactlist:
meta-contactlist-slick:
bundle-plugin-icqaccregwizz:
bundle-plugin-jabberaccregwizz:
bundle-plugin-msnaccregwizz:
bundle-plugin-sipaccregwizz:
bundle-plugin-yahooaccregwizz:
bundle-plugin-aimaccregwizz:
bundle-commons-codec:
bundle-httputil:
bundle-plugin-spellcheck:
bundle-version-impl:
      [jar] Building jar: /media/Volume/linux/eclipse/git_repos/jitsi/sc-bundles/version-impl.jar
bundle-shutdown-timeout:
bundle-windows-clean-shutdown:
bundle-growlnotification:
bundle-swingnotification:
bundle-galagonotification:
bundle-sparkle:
bundle-plugin-branding:
bundle-systemactivitynotifications:
bundle-osdependent:
bundle-browserlauncher:
bundle-systray-service:
bundle-pluginmanager:
bundle-skinmanager:
bundle-notification-service:
bundle-notification-handlers:
bundle-notification-wiring:
bundle-notification-config:
bundle-contacteventhandler:
bundle-plugin-contactinfo:
bundle-plugin-chatalerter:
bundle-keybindings:
bundle-plugin-keybindingChooser:
bundle-plugin-globalproxyconfig:
bundle-jfontchooserlib:
bundle-update:
bundle-plugin-update:
bundle-plugin-simpleaccreg:
bundle-plugin-generalconfig:
bundle-plugin-googletalkaccregwizz:
bundle-argdelegation-service:
bundle-argdelegation:
bundle-zrtp4j:
bundle-sdes4j:
bundle-json:
bundle-filehistory:
bundle-metahistory:
bundle-metahistory-slick:
bundle-plugin-facebookaccregwizz:
bundle-plugin-ippiaccregwizz:
bundle-bouncycastle:
bundle-plugin-otr:
bundle-plugin-iptelaccregwizz:
bundle-contactsource:
bundle-plugin-reconnect:
bundle-plugin-securityconfig:
bundle-plugin-advancedconfig:
bundle-credentialsstorage:
bundle-credentialsstorage-slick:
bundle-plugin-nimbuzzavatar:
bundle-custom-avatar:
bundle-replacement:
bundle-youtube:
bundle-dailymotion:
bundle-smiley:
bundle-vimeo:
bundle-vbox7:
bundle-metacafe:
bundle-flickr:
bundle-hulu:
bundle-twitpic:
bundle-directimage:
bundle-bliptv:
bundle-viddler:
bundle-plugin-chatconfig:
bundle-certificate:
bundle-packetlogging:
bundle-plugin-loggingutils:
bundle-provdisc:
bundle-provdisc-dhcp:
bundle-provdisc-mdns:
bundle-provisioning:
bundle-addrbook:
bundle-plugin-ldap:
bundle-thunderbird:
bundle-plugin-contactsourceconfig:
bundle-plugin-certconfig:
bundle-globalshortcut:
bundle-plugin-msofficecomm:
bundle-libjitsi:
bundle-customcontactactions:
bundle-phonenumbercontactsource:
bundle-demuxcontactsource:
bundle-muc:
bundle-desktoputil:
bundle-globaldisplaydetails:
bundle-usersearch:
bundle-plugin-propertieseditor:
bundle-plugin-accountinfo:
bundle-plugin-connectioninfo:
bundle-guava:
bundle-hsql:
bundles:
package:
make:
deploy-os-specific-bundles:
make-and-deploy:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 9 seconds
```

Well, 2 warnings but build successful. Seems to be fine. If I try to start the application with the run configuration given on [this page](https://jitsi.org/Documentation/ConfigureEclipseNew) it starts but... I get a wave of Errors in the background:

```
18:29:29.600 FATAL: [15] impl.sysactivity.SystemActivityNotificationsServiceImpl.getCurrentRunningManager().636 Error creating manager
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no unix-java in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
    at cx.ath.matthew.unix.UnixSocket.<clinit>(UnixSocket.java:40)
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.Transport.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.Transport.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusConnection.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.sysactivity.NetworkManagerListenerImpl.<init>(NetworkManagerListenerImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.sysactivity.SystemActivityNotificationsServiceImpl.getCurrentRunningManager(SystemActivityNotificationsServiceImpl.java:632)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.sysactivity.SystemActivityNotificationsServiceImpl.start(SystemActivityNotificationsServiceImpl.java:143)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.sysactivity.SysActivityActivator.start(SysActivityActivator.java:59)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2152)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2070)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1297)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18:29:29.603 FATAL: [15] impl.sysactivity.SystemActivityNotificationsServiceImpl.getCurrentRunningManager().636 Error creating manager
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class cx.ath.matthew.unix.UnixSocket
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.Transport.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.Transport.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusConnection.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.sysactivity.NetworkManagerListenerImpl.<init>(NetworkManagerListenerImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.sysactivity.SystemActivityNotificationsServiceImpl.getCurrentRunningManager(SystemActivityNotificationsServiceImpl.java:632)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.sysactivity.SystemActivityNotificationsServiceImpl.isSupported(SystemActivityNotificationsServiceImpl.java:586)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.netaddr.NetworkConfigurationWatcher.handleNewSystemActivityNotificationsService(NetworkConfigurationWatcher.java:176)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.netaddr.NetworkConfigurationWatcher.serviceChanged(NetworkConfigurationWatcher.java:232)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:943)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:794)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:544)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4425)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3429)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:346)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:320)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.sysactivity.SysActivityActivator.start(SysActivityActivator.java:61)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2152)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2070)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1297)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18:29:29.797 FATAL: [15] impl.hid.HIDServiceImpl.<init>().54 Error when creating Robot/NativeKeyboard instance
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hid in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.hid.NativeKeyboard.<clinit>(NativeKeyboard.java:18)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.hid.HIDServiceImpl.<init>(HIDServiceImpl.java:49)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.hid.HIDActivator.start(HIDActivator.java:48)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2152)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2070)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1297)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18:29:30.035 FATAL: [15] org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.device.DeviceConfiguration.error() Failed to register custom Renderer org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.jmfext.media.renderer.audio.PulseAudioRenderer with JMF.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: audioSystem
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.jmfext.media.renderer.audio.PulseAudioRenderer.<init>(PulseAudioRenderer.java:112)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.jmfext.media.renderer.audio.PulseAudioRenderer.<init>(PulseAudioRenderer.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.device.DeviceConfiguration.registerCustomRenderers(DeviceConfiguration.java:1034)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.device.DeviceConfiguration.<init>(DeviceConfiguration.java:355)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.MediaServiceImpl.<init>(MediaServiceImpl.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at org.jitsi.impl.libjitsi.LibJitsiImpl.getService(LibJitsiImpl.java:142)
    at org.jitsi.impl.libjitsi.LibJitsiOSGiImpl.getService(LibJitsiOSGiImpl.java:86)
    at org.jitsi.service.libjitsi.LibJitsi.invokeGetServiceOnImpl(LibJitsi.java:163)
    at org.jitsi.service.libjitsi.LibJitsi.getMediaService(LibJitsi.java:115)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.neomedia.NeomediaActivator.start(NeomediaActivator.java:380)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2152)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2070)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1297)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18:29:30.039 FATAL: [15] org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.device.DeviceConfiguration.error() Failed to register custom Renderer org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.jmfext.media.renderer.video.JAWTRenderer with JMF.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnawtrenderer in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.jmfext.media.renderer.video.JAWTRenderer.<clinit>(JAWTRenderer.java:90)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.device.DeviceConfiguration.registerCustomRenderers(DeviceConfiguration.java:1034)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.device.DeviceConfiguration.<init>(DeviceConfiguration.java:355)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.MediaServiceImpl.<init>(MediaServiceImpl.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at org.jitsi.impl.libjitsi.LibJitsiImpl.getService(LibJitsiImpl.java:142)
    at org.jitsi.impl.libjitsi.LibJitsiOSGiImpl.getService(LibJitsiOSGiImpl.java:86)
    at org.jitsi.service.libjitsi.LibJitsi.invokeGetServiceOnImpl(LibJitsi.java:163)
    at org.jitsi.service.libjitsi.LibJitsi.getMediaService(LibJitsi.java:115)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.neomedia.NeomediaActivator.start(NeomediaActivator.java:380)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2152)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2070)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1297)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18:29:30.142 FATAL: [32] util.UtilActivator.uncaughtException().108 An uncaught exception occurred in thread=Thread[Thread-14,5,main] and message was: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.zrtp.ZrtpFortunaEntropyGatherer$GatherAudio.run(ZrtpFortunaEntropyGatherer.java:267)
**
Gtk:ERROR:/tmp/buildd/gtk+2.0-2.24.10/gtk/gtkaccelmap.c:113:_gtk_accel_map_init: assertion failed: (accel_entry_ht == NULL)
```

On the other side the client appears and I can login with my account. If I start an other client and log in with one more account, this account appears as online. The network communication seems to work ...a bit :/ 
I can send a message to the other client and this client receive this message correctly but if I want to receive a message with the jitsi client I get the message but I also get some Exceptions:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.zrtp.ZrtpFortunaEntropyGatherer$GatherAudio.run(ZrtpFortunaEntropyGatherer.java:267)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no globalshortcut in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.globalshortcut.NativeKeyboardHook.<clinit>(NativeKeyboardHook.java:254)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.globalshortcut.GlobalShortcutServiceImpl.<init>(GlobalShortcutServiceImpl.java:56)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.globalshortcut.GlobalShortcutActivator.start(GlobalShortcutActivator.java:101)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2152)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2070)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1297)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jdic_misc in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
    at org.jdesktop.jdic.misc.impl.LinuxAlerter.<init>(LinuxAlerter.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at org.jdesktop.jdic.misc.Alerter.loadLinux(Unknown Source)
    at org.jdesktop.jdic.misc.Alerter.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.plugin.chatalerter.ChatAlerterActivator.start(ChatAlerterActivator.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2152)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2070)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1297)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18:37:33.762 FATAL: [83] util.UtilActivator.uncaughtException().108 An uncaught exception occurred in thread=Thread[pool-8-thread-1,5,main] and message was: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.notify.AudioSystemClipImpl.exitRunOnceInPlayThread(AudioSystemClipImpl.java:115)
    at org.jitsi.service.audionotifier.AbstractSCAudioClip.runInPlayThread(AbstractSCAudioClip.java:375)
    at org.jitsi.service.audionotifier.AbstractSCAudioClip.access$100(AbstractSCAudioClip.java:20)
    at org.jitsi.service.audionotifier.AbstractSCAudioClip$1.run(AbstractSCAudioClip.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Not really surprising cause of the errors during the clients start. I don't know how to get this project running well. I exactly followed the [guide](https://jitsi.org/Documentation/ConfigureEclipseNew) from [jitsi.org](https://jitsi.org) and the client starts but it is very buggy.
Could anyone help me to get this project running?

Thanks a lot in advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out that the [instructions](https://jitsi.org/Documentation/ConfigureEclipseNew#toc2) for linux are incorrect. I solved the problems by adding this line to the VM arguments in the run configurations:

```
-Djava.library.path=./lib/native/linux-64
```

and changed the path variable to this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PATH:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:./lib/native/linux-64
```

I didn't expect an error in the instruction. It's very annoying but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success following these instructions: https://jitsi.org/Documentation/ConfigureEclipseNew#toc2

Comment: You did it with linux? These are exactly the same instruction I used.

Comment: @MutenRoshi I did, but I'm on 32 bit linux. Thanks for sharing your solution.